# OcaIDE Installation on Eclipse on Mac not working

Tags: eclipse, macos, installation, ocaml

I'm trying to install OcaIDE on my mac, but after following all the instructions on the website, I am still not able open perspective to OCaml, or see OcaIDE in the preferences page. I have tried the manual install as well. Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try these instructions (they might be a bit different than what you might be following):

1. In Eclipse, click *Help » Install New Software...*
2. In *Work* with, enter *http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide* then click *Add*, *OK*.
3. Check *OcaIDE* and click *Next*, *Next*, *I accept*, and *Finish* to accept the license and install the software. Eclipse will prompt you to accept unsigned code.
4. Click *Restart Now*. After Eclipse restarts, close the Welcome tab and click *Window » Open Perspective » Other... » OCaml*.
5. Go to *Eclipse » Preferences*. Click on "+" or "▶" next to OcaIDE to expand the tree and then click on *Paths*. If all the paths in this panel (except for possibly make and omake) are already filled in, then continue to the next step. Otherwise, click *Browse* next to OCaml Binaries Directory and choose the "bin" directory inside your OCaml installation directory (for example, /usr...). Then press *Apply*. Eclipse should fill in additional path values for you (ocaml, ocamlc, etc).
6. Under *Other tools » OCaml lib path*, click *Browse* and choose the "lib" directory inside your ObjectiveCaml   installation directory. Press *OK* to close the dialog.
7. Near the top right of Eclipse, you should see an OCaml button and Java button, with the Ocaml button selected. If you only see the Java button, click the button to the left which looks like a window with a yellow "+" sign, and then double click on "OCaml". You should be in OCaml mode.